# NESTED FOR LOOP - Swift 2

Tags: for-loop, swift2, nested-loops

I have no coding experience other than this book

Programming Swift! Swift 2 Kindle Edition
by Nick Smith (Author)

I am currently at Chapter

5.3 Nested FOR LOOPS

//  NESTED FOR LOOP #2

This code -

```
for var a = 0; a < 11; a++ {
    print("")

    for var b = 0; b < a; b++ {
        print("*", terminator: " ")

    }

}
```

[GENERATES THIS PATTERN...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InmWp.jpg)

Now [after several/ 4 hours 'odd'] I SIMPLY CAN'T WORK OUT [HOW TO CHANGE THE ABOVE 'simple' [if you know how] CODE TO GENERATE THIS PATTERN??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2WRB.jpg)

I (think I) can see Outer and Inner loops I just can't work out the rest!?? I have tried every variation I can think of!?? (and am aware that just doing 'permutations' doesn't mean I have true understanding of what I am trying to do!...)

Tried using --operators and changing [most/ all] values [but 'permutations' is a limited method]

I feel like a total fool but figure if it's the very first time I've seen this stuff maybe it's not so bad, these things take learning!??

Help (the answer LOL) would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: `for var b = 0; b < 10 - a; b++ {`?

Comment: eric thank you, for the solution and the advice, its painfully simple when you know how

Comment: @BenGee333 What I meant is that I believe that learning Swift with such low quality examples is not a good thing. Maybe I was a bit direct in my comment, sorry. :) But my recommendation about the Apple ebook still stands.

Comment: Agreed with @EricD. Here, if you want to continue reading this book go ahead, just please also read the apple book. It's great :)

Comment: no eric i understood what you were saying :-) my comment was the result of 4 or 5 hours of frustration and lack of true understanding, the 1 min represented your answer LOL i tried everything EXCEPT that your explanation was perfect and i totally appreciate it :-))) the instant i input it into playgrounds the beautiful pattern appeared. i will take your advice and will start the Apple Swift 2 book page 1 tomorrow , right now i'll end my day on a win THANK YOU :-)))

Comment: @vale i agree with you about apple book. i don't know anything about Nick Smith's book.

Comment: Oh just a detail: @trojanfoe is the one who gave you the hint in his comment, not me. // Enjoy your learning journey, Swift is awesome. :)

Comment: also you don't know what's good or not till you start reading and trying, getting stuck and asking , it took a wee while to build up 'the bottle' to even ask here, i felt stupid to ask something so simple but i thought i'm going to just do it, this way i have the solution AND good advice, thinking about it why would you learn an Apple language from anyone other than Apple!??? thanks again. Ben :-)))

Comment: haha Eric D. "Oh just a detail: trojanfoe is the one who gave you the hint in his comment, not me." total class ! :-DDD @trojanfoe thank you, thank you and thanks to all who replied and helped. like i said I'll start the Apple book tomorrow, page 1 :-))) night all :-)))

Comment: THANK YOU TO user3441734 and gnasher729 for the AWESOME ANSWERS GIVEN in reply to my post :-DDD ALSO THANKS TO angelcool.net for the 'edit' of my original post, in asking a SINGLE QUESTION i have learnt a GREAT DEAL MORE than the ONE ANSWER I was hoping for and I will ensure (should I ask another question) that the post is correctly formatted. AGAIN THANKS TO ALL who have replied and helped with on this post :-DDD now to page 1... LOL

Comment: @trojanfoe haha just don't want to miss anyone out or be seen to be being ungrateful, [as you can probably tell it's my] first post and will make sure future ones [if any] are much better though out, presented and less thank you, thank you, thank you LOL ;-))) ONE LAST POINT [question]: I notice this post (now has) has a -2 (MINUS 2) rating!?? is that saying that the question I asked shows that I didn't do any research? or is it indicating the number of Answers given??

Comment: Yeah it's a tough crowd here and things get downvoted out of spite.  It's a very basic question and some people treat those with contempt.  Don't worry about it.  I'll upvote to give you some points to get going.

Comment: @trojanfoe I’d say two words but I haven’t won an Oscar ;-)

So in lieu of that I’ll say

People can be so impatient, someone arrives on their first day of ‘school’ & gets ‘detention’ for not knowing the same amount as those who've been here for years LOL

My view is if I get asked, know it & can help [within reason] I’d help! But I guess that’s easy to say when I’m the one asking.

Anyway the help/ answer was given, I’ve learnt A LOT from the experience of having asked so I can now press on..

If I ever get good at ‘this stuff’ I vow to be as generous as the people who responded to this post.

Comment: @trojanfoe you’re right I won’t worry about it [too much] but 'just for the record', if anyone knew the amount I [like many] have done to even get to this forum. I have no coding experience but HAVE BEEN reading & abortively starting & stopping (about 5) app building courses & coding books (because have all lacked, & pose more questions than answers) leading me to this resource. That’s been going on since September 2015, before that I’ve been mulling the idea for [years &] years!. So 'strictly speaking’ I have done PLENTY of 'research effort'!? [Surely] These things take time & follow a path!?

Comment: All of that [unnecessarily but 'just for the record'] said @Eric D. said “Enjoy your learning journey, Swift is awesome. :)” I couldn’t agree more :-DDD Coding is the most exciting [in terms of intellectual possibilities] thing I have ever embarked on [it's literally melting my mind LOL ;-)))] but [for those who can’t remember] the beginning can be a bit of a struggle LOL Anyway now to start looking at the Apple Swift 2 ebook, PAGE ONE, onwards ... And I'll be keeping my mouth shut till I have something I really can't get past... PAGE TWO LOL Only kidding ;-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this systematically: If you want to got for example user3441734's output: There are 11 lines. We number the lines from 0 to 10. So we have a loop that sets line to the values 0 to 10.

```
for var line = 0; line < 11; ++line
```

Next, what do we want to print in each line? In line 0 we want to print 11 * characters. In line 10 we want to print 1 star character. The number of stars is 11 - line. How do I get the expression 11 - line? The number of stars goes down as line goes up, so it must be something - line. When line = 0 there must be 11 stars, so something - 0 = 11, and something = 11. So the first line in the loop:

```
let starcount = 11 - line
```

Then we want to print (star count) times a star and a space character, follow by starting a new line.

```
for var star = 0; star < starcount; ++star {
    print ("*", terminator: " ")
}
print ("")
```

All together:

```
for var line = 0; line < 11; ++line {
    let starcount = 11 - line
    for var star = 0; start < star count; ++star {
        print ("*", terminator: " ")
    }
    print ("")
}
```

And we simplify the loops a bit:

```
for var line in 0 ..< 11 {
    let starcount = 11 - line
    for var star in 0 ..< starcount {
        print ("*", terminator: " ")
    }
    print ("")
}
```

If you wanted a different pattern, all you have to do is change the number 11 if the number of lines is different, and change the calculation of starcount. Actually it would be better to have a variable for linecount as well, so changing for a different pattern is even easier:

```
let linecount = 11
for var line in 0 ..< line count {
    let starcount = linecount - line
    for var star in 0 ..< starcount {
        print ("*", terminator: " ")
    }
    print ("")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for var a = 10; a > 0; a-- { 

    for var b = 0; b < a; b++ {
        print("*", terminator: " ")

    }
    print()
}
```

prints

```
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

UPDATE for nowadays Swift syntax, with the same functionality

```
for a in stride(from: 10, through: 0, by: -1) {
    for _ in stride(from: 0, to: a, by: 1) {
        print("*", terminator: " ")
    }
    print()
}
```

Comment: for indexLine in stride(from: 10, to: 0, by: -1) {
            for _ in stride(from: 0, to: indexLine, by: 1) {
                print("*", terminator: " ")
            }
            print("\n")
        }